# Comparison: Pycharm vs WingIDE

Tags: python, comparison, pycharm, wing-ide

Which one do you prefer?

Which features does one have that the other doesn't (in their latest versions, of course)?

Both IDEs have trial versions at their respective websites:

http://wingware.com/

http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is the kind of question someone could answer for you. As they both provide trial licenses, you really should try each one for your everyday coding, and you'll then know which one fits best your needs.

Comment: But if you really want my opinion, i personally prefer (and use) PyCharm.

Comment: The question is not, "Which one is better?"  The question is: "What features are present in one, but not the other?" and "Which one do you prefer?" That's all.